# Xpath for element without unique Id or text argument

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have this HTML definition and I'm getting mad trying to click "Search" button:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
         <td>
             <button class="gwt-Button" type="button" style="width: 75px">Search</button>
         <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
             <button class="gwt-Button" type="button" style="width: 75px">Remove</button>
         <td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The point here is that the buttons do not have a "Text" argument or unique identifier, just the texts 'Search' or 'Remove.
I'm using robotframework with selenium library. things already tried (unsuccessfully):

Click Button  //button[@type='button']/span[.='Search']

Click Button  //button[@type='button']/span[.='Search']/.

Click Button  //span[contains(text()='Search')]

Click Button  //button[@type, 'button' and text()='Search']

Click Button  //button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Search')]

Click Button  //button[@type='button' and span='Search']

Click Button  //html/body/*[contains(text()='Search')]

Click Button  //span[text()='Search']/input[@type="radio"]

Click Button  //span[text()='Search']

Click Button  //span[label[text()='Search']]/input[@type="radio"]

Click Button  //button[.//text()='Search']

Click Button  //button[nomralize-space()='Search']

Click Button  //html/body/*[., 'Search']

Click Button  //button[.,'Search']

Click Button  //span[.,'Search']

Click Button  //button/span[text()='Search']

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This should work if there are no similar elements in your HTML.

```
Click Element    xpath=//button[contains(text(), 'Search')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad practics (although inner-text using is also bad practics - choose what is more suitable), but you can use searching by order:

`//tbody/tr[1]//button`